# flyway check if column exists in Java

Tags: exists, flyway

I am new to Flyway, but this tool seemed to be something I was looking for. I have played a little bit with it, and I was very eager on learning the JdbcMigration. However, I'm a little bit disappointed about this interface. I had expected some additional helpers that tell me whether a table, view, table column, sequence etc. already exists. Is there a way to get this information from flyway? Or do I have to look for some other tools?

Answer (score 0):

Flyway currently doesn't expose such an abstraction. You have to use either the Jdbc metadata from the connection or query the information schema yourself.

Feel free to file a feature request in the issue tracker.